# Simulate urban city roads

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, sdf, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I wanted to simulate a busy urban road,similar to **Darpa Urban Challenge** for an autonomous self-driving-car. I'm in search of simulators for that.

I've seen gazebo since its integration with ROS is easier but editing world files or indeed creating them itself is difficult. In torcs simulator I have seen many world files but not many sensors. I don't want much physics in my simulation. **I want a light weight simulator(for checking out path planning on an urban road) and in which creating roads are easier.**

I've even searched for gazebo sdf files similar to urban city but in vain.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172021/simulate-urban-city-roads/) by [Dpp_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/18691/dpp_coder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2014-05-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I´m not sure about other simulators, but here are some Gazebo-related links that might be useful:

- As described in the
  [animate_pose](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/intermediate/animate_pose)
  tutorial, you can animate objects
  without using the physics engine. If
  you have a model of one or multiple
  cars, it should be possible to let
  them move using this mechanism.
- There has been some work on importing
  Open Street Map data into Gazebo,
  [code
  here](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_osm).
  I´m not sure how mature and finished
  this is, though.
- The driving scenario from the VRC
  competition as visible in [this
  video](http://youtu.be/3rpiqZZ6lNk?t=2m54s)
  is available as part of
  [drcsim](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/fb860e62722c449868fa395e3eece367b3ac0b4a/drcsim_model_resources/worlds/?at=default)
  (vrc_task_1.world) and might be
  useful to look at.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dpp_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/18691/dpp_coder/) on 2014-05-30**:
That was great .. Thank you but Is there an easier way to create a world like that in gazebo?

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-06-02**:
Great, importing OSM into Gazebo sounds interesting. Thanks for tip ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The UTAustin team has a simulator for their vehicle that might be a good starting point: http://wiki.ros.org/simulator_art

I can't tell if it simulates other vehicles on the road or not, but it isn't that difficult to add.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-05-31**:
Our A.R.T. vehicle was retired last year and those packages are no longer maintained. The simulation used stage (2D), with roads defined via the DARPA Road Network Definition File. It should still run on Groovy and maybe Hydro, but there are no plans to convert it to catkin.